# How to draw these graphs in LaTeX

Tags: diagrams, graphs

Is it possible to draw graphs like in image below in LaTeX? Can you offer some basic codes or examples for me so that I can take a look?
[image]
[image]

Comment: At least with `TikZ` and `pstricks` (for the latter, more precisely with `pst-node`).

Comment: Looks like one possibility would be the [`PGF/TikZ`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgf?lang=en)-based  [`forest`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/forest) package. But see the [CTAN node for 'tree'](https://www.ctan.org/topic/tree) for more options.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436). Yes, TikZ for example can indeed be used to draw such an image. Questions about how to draw specific graphics that just post an image of the desired result are really not reasonable questions to ask on the site. Please post a minimal compilable document showing that you've tried to produce the image and then people will be happy to help you with any specific problems you may have.  See [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) for what needs to go into such a document.

Comment: Yes. Assuming you can decipher the text, which I can't, you can draw them in several ways. As stated, this fully answers your question. This seems to be not such a do-it-for-me but a do-these-several-things-for-me. Or else the answer really is simply 'yes'.

Comment: Although you could use Forest for this, the graph drawing algorithms available with LuaTeX are probably more suitable here judging by the variable weighting of the graphs. However, that might just be a function of variations in hand drawing and a strange skewed perspective. Impossible to tell, really, what 'like these' means in this context. (If there were regularity, I'd say Forest, but there doesn't appear to be any.)

Comment: @cfr  are there examples to follow?

Comment: Yes, @Katherine, lots and lots and lots of them.

Comment: Asking people to provide examples is asking people to duplicate what people have already done, including the people you are asking in many cases. This site has lots and lots of examples of all the packages mentioned in the comments: `pstricks`, `tikz`, `forest` etc. The Ti*k*Z example site has more. The manuals of these packages have many, many more. `texdoc tikz` `texdoc forest` etc. Or browse the documentation on CTAN.

Comment: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/forest, http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tikz-pgf (general), http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/trees, http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/graphs, http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pstricks (general) etc.

Comment: Also, look in the Ti*k*Z manual sec 29 in the version I have, `Graph Drawing Layouts: Trees`. There's an example on p. 409 which looks similar.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### *In my view, I ought not answer this question as it is just a do-it-for-me - indeed, do-these-for-me.*

## *Caveat emptor ...*

Here's an example using Ti*k*Z's graph drawing algorithms. Requires LuaTeX. I can't even read most your what's in your image but presumably you can, so you can adapt the example as needed. Reference is to the example on page 409 I mentioned above.

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{luatex85,tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{graphs,graphdrawing,positioning,quotes}
\usegdlibrary{trees}
\begin{document}
\tikzset{
  graphs/my graph/.style={extended binary tree layout, sibling distance=7mm, level distance=7mm, math nodes},
  baseline=(current bounding box.center),
}
\tikz{
  \graph [grow'=up, my graph]
  {
    I -- { a -- ab[second] -- aba[second] -- abab -- d/"" , b -- a^{-1}b[second] -- a^{-1}ba[second] -- c/""[second] }
  };
}
$\Rightarrow$
\tikz{
  \graph [grow'=45, my graph, nodes={circle, draw, inner sep=.5pt}]
  {
    o/"" --["$b$"] b/"" --["$c$"] c/""[fill, second] -- d/"" -- e/""[fill, second] ;
    o/"" --["$a$"'] a/""[fill] --["$a^{-1}$"'] a^{-1}/""[second]  -- { f/"" -- h/""[second,fill] , g/""[fill] -- i/""[second] };
  };
}
\end{document}
```

[image: graph transformations]

If there's a pattern, I'd have Forest draw them automatically if I had to do many similar trees. If there's no pattern, I'd have Forest draw them less automatically. If I only needed a few trees, I'd use Forest.

But there are a zillion Forest examples on the site, including several tutorial-style answers, so you can easily use Forest if you wish.